# wkhtmltopdf css sizes in cm/mm

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I use wkhtmltopdf to produce A4 sized PDFs. When I create a `<div>` tag and set its style to `height: 297mm; width: 210mm` (which is the defined size of A4), set wkhtmltopdf's margin settings to 0 (`wkhtmltopdf -B 0 -T 0 -L 0 -R 0 ...`) and give the `<div>` a red background, I can see a thin white line at the bottom of the page, i.e. the `<div>` is not filling the page completely. This is happening consistently with 0.11.0 rc1 (the latest version) on Debian and with 0.10.0 rc2 on Mac OS X.

Has anyone else seen this? Is this a known problem, or is there a workaround?

Comment: I have experienced this consistently as well and would Love to see a solution.

Comment: I have experienced something similar on the latest version, running CentOS.

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, trying to produce an 8.5x11 inch document. I switched my command to Letter instead of A4 and that did it - also I adjusted my container to 215.9mm × 279.4mm. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Well, Letter and A4 are two different sizes, and the first thing I did try was `page-size A4` and 210mm x 297mm... it's intersting to know, though, that Letter seems to work properly.

Comment: A way to debug wkhtmltopdf is to download Qt web browser and see if that white line still appears in the browser.

Comment: Use the `--disable-smart-shrinking` flag, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a method that worked for me that used margins.

```
style="margin:0,auto"
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
style="margin:0,auto,0,auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this flag for wkhtmltopdf: `--disable-smart-shrinking` - when you use this, the dimensions are resolved as given, so A4 will be **almost** 210mm x 297mm like expected.

However, over the course of ~40+ pages, it seems a height of 297.25mm is safe.

`wkhtmltopdf -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 -B 0 -s A4 --disable-smart-shrinking doc.html doc.pdf`

Without using it, so with this magical smart shrinking enabled, a full A4 page for me is

```
{
  width: 991px;
  height: 1403px;
}
```

or

```
{
  width: 262.2mm;
  height: 371.25mm;
}
```

Tested with 33 pages of that size

[image: Tested with 33 pages of that size]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try increasing the height of the `<div>` a fraction of a mm?

`height: 297.5mm` or `height: 298mm` instead?

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try set `<div>` element `style="margin: 0;"` in my case this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but after some tries (border red on a div), I figured that the wkhtmltopdf default A4 page is about 1000px wide, and 1425px tall.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I will formulate it in a full answer

Answer (score 0):

Default for A4 will be dependant of getting metric sheet ratios correct, and sadly there are too many wrong answers.

default as px will naturally be rounded off in applications as px should be integers thus unreal

A4 as pixels based on a (incorrect assumption there are a fixed number of 96 per inch)

```
  width: 793.701px;
  height: 1122.52px;
```

QT Web Kit uses 160dpi
thus it will work with

```
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 992.126px;
  height: 1403.15px; 
}
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
  height: 1393.15px;
}
```

Ideally the Media when printing should also be set

```
    <style>
@media print {
@page { size: 210mm,297mm; }
}
body {
```

[image]

The big issue is the use of WebKit **scale by default**

> --enable-smart-shrinking
> Enable the intelligent shrinking strategy
> used by WebKit that makes the pixel/dpi
> ratio non-constant (default)

This means that for A4 wide @100% we need a different value
and from trial and error you may find this works

```
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.myDiv {
  background-color: red;    
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1052.9pt;
}
```

So for HTML graphics like these where 96 is the norm we need to add an over-ride **`--disable-smart-shrinking`**

And the correct ratio and scale will be used

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe  -B 0 -T 0 -L 0 -R 0 -s A4 --disable-smart-shrinking red.htm red.pdf
```

And the result should be perfect.
[image]

A Secondary problem is different browsers use different rounding off strategy when determining PDF units, thus the value for FireFox may need a small adjustment for Chromium! and visa versa!