# what css level does wkhtmltopdf support 8/2015

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt)`

While most CSS3 stuff - at least what I use - works fine, some need a '`-webkit-`' prefix, like `transform`

Others, like `border-image` seem to work only with the short form (and prefixed). ie. border-image-xxx, seem not to work, `SVG` seems not to be supported at all

So the question: How can I find out, what level of CSS3 support `wkhtmltopdf` has? Trial and error is very time consuming, and probably erronous, because of typos.

**edid: based on answer**

I am testing with Chrome, FF, IE, Opera & safari (as possible with windows), wkhtmltopdf is like an own browser - sorringliy its seems not big enough to get a place in 'official' lists

Comment: Still no concrete answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It uses CSS2 - to my knowledge, no CSS3 properties will work.

Answer (score -2):

`wkhtmltopdf` uses `webkit`. This is used by Safari and Chrome as well.

Details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

So if you check http://caniuse.com for these browsers you should get a good result.

Final tests are still a good thing though.

Some examples of questions asked here

[wkhtmltopdf css sizes in cm/mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180079/wkhtmltopdf-css-sizes-in-cm-mm)

[Does wkhtmltopdf respect css font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176758/does-wkhtmltopdf-respect-css-font-color?rq=1)

[Does wkHTMLtoPDF support @page rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165208/does-wkhtmltopdf-support-page-rules?rq=1)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is like an own browser, and reacts different than safari & chrome

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So there is a need for a suite of test cases for ``wkhtmltopdf``. I wonder where we find candidates for an existing suite to be run through ``wkhtmltopdf``?

Comment: hm, why an own set? In prinziple the cases for "other" browsers should do in a first step, ok, not tests for pdf specific things like page break,  but css sould work. or not?

Comment: Cases of "other" browsers are OK and are needed as well. But wkhtmltopdf is for printing and that needs specific test cases.

Comment: hm, but you need optical testcase check in both cases, dont you?